# Trying to pull data from two different arrays (string and image) with a single random number

Tags: arrays

Trying to pull data from two different arrays (string and image) with a single random number and getting a type conflict.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Image: UIImageView!

let animalNames = ["flag", "hammer", "shoe"]

let animalImages = ["flagImage", "hammerImage", "shoeImage"]


@IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {

    let randomItem = Int(arc4random() % UInt32(animalNames.count))

    label1.text = "\(animalNames[randomItem])"

    Image.image = (animalImages[randomItem])

}

override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {

}
```

}

Comment: Hi Alan - you need to put your code in the actual question not an image of it… have a read of [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Images are just not visible to some users…

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please avoid posting code as an image since people cannot copy and paste it to test in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The important parts of your code are:

```
let animalNames = ["flag", "hammer", "shoe"]
let animalImages = ["flagImage", "hammerImage", "shoeImage"]
```

Both `animalNames` and `animalImages` are of type `[String]` (an array of strings)

You are trying to set the `image` property of the `UIImageView` which is an object of type `UIImage?`. i.e. it's an `optional` image, it doesn't have to exist.

The problem occurs because you are getting the `String` from the array of `animalImages` when what you need to do is load an actual image.

If the `animalImages` array in your code contains the names of image files (`.jpg`, `.png` etc) in your project then you can use `UIImage(named: String)` method like this:

```
let randomItem = Int(arc4random() % UInt32(animalNames.count))
let randomFileName = animalImages[randomItem]
let randomImage = UIImage(named: randomFileName)

Image.image = randomImage
```

Comment: Is that going to generate a second random number?

Comment: No I was just using your existing line for the random number…

Comment: I am getting- "Definition conflicts with previous value"

Comment: Glad to help  - don’t forget to accept the answer 